# SQL > Select multiple rows for single result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image: SQL Table]

I have the above table, what I need to do is, for example based off this image, have a single row returned that would show:

```
Ticket ID |       Created       |       Assigned      | Time Difference  
    2     | 2015-05-31 09:18:44 | 2015-06-03 10:05:00 | $MATH_RESULT
```

This image only shows one example but I'd like to have it return each ticket that has both an 'assigned' time and a 'created' time.

I'm not DBA and this is a bit beyond my limited knowledge.  Can someone help me on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: So you expect us to complete this task for you?

Comment: I was looking for more of an education than solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join` to find the row with state "assigned" for the row in state "created":

```
select  c.ticket_id
,       c.timestamp
,       a.timestamp
,       datediff(a.timestamp, c.timestamp)
from    ticket c
join    ticket a
on      c.ticket_id = a.ticket_id
where   c.state = 'created'
        and a.state = 'assigned'
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Can you explain what's happening so I can better understand for the future? (And I'll also mark your answer when it will let me in 5 minutes).

Comment: You can play around by removing the conditions or joins to see how it works.  Basically you start with all rows in "created" and alias that to "c", then look up the rows with matching ticket id and state "assigned", and lias that to "a".

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf498/3

```
SELECT t.ticket_id,t.timestamp as created, t1.timestamp as assigned, (t1.timestamp - t.timestamp) as delay
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t.ticket_id = t1.ticket_id
  AND t1.state = 'assigned'
WHERE t.ticket_id = 2
   and t.state = 'created'
```

or if you need list of all tickets

```
SELECT t.ticket_id,t.timestamp as created, t1.timestamp as assigned, (t1.timestamp - t.timestamp) as delay
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t.ticket_id = t1.ticket_id
  AND t1.state = 'assigned'
WHERE t.state = 'created'
```